# JPanel on CardLayout Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am new to Java and I am making a navigation through `CardLayout` in Swing. Basically I have two buttons on a `JFrame` and when I click on one button it should go to card 1 where I have kept two buttons on `JPanel`, `card1` and when I click on another button it should go to card 2 where I have kept a `JTextField` on panel `card2`. But it is not happening.

Can anyone fix it?

My code is as below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;  

public class CardLayoutTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f;
    JButton b;
    JButton c;
    JPanel panel;
    JPanel cards;
    JPanel card1;
    JPanel card2;
    CardLayout card;  
    Container pane;     
    final String card1Text = "One";
    final String card2Text = "Two";

    CardLayoutTest() {

     }  

    public void passBtn() {
        f=new JFrame("Card Layout Test");

        card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 1 - Card 1"));
        card1.add(new JButton("Button 2 - Card 1"));
        card1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));

        card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.add(new JTextField("TextField on Card 2", 20));
        card2.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0)); 

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cards.add(card1, card1Text);
        cards.add(card2, card2Text); 

        b = new JButton("Page 1");
        b.setBounds(50,50,70,30);        
        b.setBackground(Color.red);

        c = new JButton("Page 2");
        c.setBounds(50,80,70,30);        
        c.setBackground(Color.blue);

        pane = f.getContentPane();
        pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                    
                    card.show(card1, card1Text);                    
                }
        });

        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                                    
                card.show(card2, card2Text);                
            }
    });
        f.add(b); f.add(c); f.add(panel); f.add(cards);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        new CardLayoutTest();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: did you have a look here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html?

Comment: Since you never initialize `card`, I assume you are getting NullPointerExceptions.  You also never use `card` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
card = new CardLayout();
cards = new JPanel(card);
```

instead of `cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());`

**UPDATE**

```
public class CardLayoutTest extends JFrame {
    JButton b;
    JButton c;
    JPanel cards;
    JPanel card1;
    JPanel card2;
    CardLayout card;
    final String card1Text = "One";
    final String card2Text = "Two";

    CardLayoutTest() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        passBtn();
    }

    public void passBtn() {
        card1 = new JPanel();
        card1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));

        card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.add(new JTextField("TextField on Card 2", 20));
        card2.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0));

        //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
        card = new CardLayout();
        cards = new JPanel(card);
        cards.add(card1, card1Text);
        cards.add(card2, card2Text);

        b = new JButton("Page 1");
        b.setBounds(50, 50, 70, 30);
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        card1.add(b);
        c = new JButton("Page 2");
        c.setBounds(50, 80, 70, 30);
        c.setBackground(Color.blue);
        card1.add(c);
        add(cards);
        card.show(cards, card1Text);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    card.show(cards, card1Text);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    card.show(cards, card2Text);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardLayoutTest cardLayoutTest = new CardLayoutTest();
        cardLayoutTest.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with `cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());`?

Comment: you don`t assign to your field and than in your action listeners use null value

Comment: The code if full of mistakes. `cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());` is not an error and doing what you suggested will not solve the problem.

Comment: Hi ZhenyaM. Thanks it works. I would like to have b and c button on card 2 also. So, I added card2.add(b); and card2.add(c). But It shows a blank page. But if I create a new button called "d" and add as card2.add(d) it works. As I have many cards and many buttons are common for navigation, I would like to use common button for all the panels. Is it possible.

Comment: If i understand right, you can not add one button to few panels - it will not work. But you can add one `ActionListener` for few buttons and got expected behavior.